# How to build an android style action bar overflow using jquery mobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, android-actionbar, styles

I am trying to add an Andriod style action bar to my app using jQuery mobile. Specifically I want to emulate the "Action Overflow" which is labeled #4 on this [page](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html). It's hard for me to believe this hasn't been done before so I don't want to reinvent the wheel. If it hasn't been done I suspect there is a good reason. Currently I am using these [guidelines](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html) in my app. but I would like to make it look more like action bar (obviously).

Is it known by some other concept? Or is it that Jquery Mobile doesn't really have the same concept?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of anything like that. I would suggest starting with a [Layout Grid](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-grids.html) in your Header. Here is a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/YTGKs/4/

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
        <div class="ui-grid-c">
            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 40px;">
                <a href="#back" data-rel="back"><img src="" style="display: block; width: 40px; height: 40px;"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"  style="width: 75%">Action Bar</div>
            <div class="ui-block-c" style="width: 40px;">
                <span class="ui-btn-inner">
                    <a href="#search"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-search"></span></a>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-d" style="width: 40px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Hello JQuery Mobile</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will help you create a Action Bar like you want and you cna set it up to do what you need, use your own images, and fit your own styles.

*Edit:* Updated to cleaner example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/YTGKs/4/

Comment: Here is another example that uses just the header bar: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/XPJq6/

`<div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
    <a href="#back" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true">Back</a>
    <a href="#search" data-role="button" data-icon="search" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right" style="margin-right: 30px;">Search</a>
    <a href="#settings" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" class="ui-btn-right">Settings</a>
    <h2>Action Bar</h2>
</div>`